# Assigning click event to dynamically created buttons

Tags: jquery

I have an object of character objects that stores their  names, attributes, image sources, etc. I then dynamically created buttons for each character with an ID set to their name. when a character is selected(clicked) it assigns that character as the player for the game and then creates buttons for every other character as an enemy. This works and essentially sets up the game.

```
$(".character-box").on("click", function(){
$("#charactercontainer").attr("style","visibility:hidden");
var selector = $(this).attr("id");
var enemyCount = 1;
for (var i=1; i<5; i++){
    if (selector == spriteObject["sprite"+i].name){
        player = spriteObject["sprite"+i];
    }
    else{
        enemies["enemy"+ enemyCount] = spriteObject["sprite"+i];
        enemyCount ++;
    }
}
var myPlayer = $("<img>");
myPlayer.attr("src", player.imgsrc);
myPlayer.addClass("flipped gameSprite");
$("#playerbox").append(myPlayer);
for(var j = 1; j<4; j++){
    var myEnemy = $("<button>");
    var enemyimage = $("<img>");
    var enemyName = enemies["enemy"+j].name;
    var enemyImgSrc = enemies["enemy"+j].imgsrc;
    myEnemy.attr("id",(enemyName+"BAD"));
    myEnemy.addClass("character-box enemyplayer");
    enemyimage.attr("src", enemyImgSrc);
    enemyimage.addClass("gameSprite")
    $("#enemybox").append(myEnemy);
    $("#"+enemyName+"BAD").append(enemyimage);

};
$(".gameSprite").animate({ height: "100px", width: "100px" });
});
```

now i want to add functionality to these "enemy" buttons and have an alert to test the code but the click event doesn't seem to bind to the buttons.

```
// when a enemy is selected to attack create gameply
$(".enemyplayer").on("click", function(){
alert("lets fight");
});
```

Comment: When is the binding code being executed?

Comment: Change your code like this
`$(document).on("click",".enemyplayer", function(){
alert("lets fight");
});`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Thanks! another question if you dont mind me asking: Could you explain why the click event for the .enemyplayer button doesn't even though it has the exact same syntax as the .character-box button? both buttons were dynamically created

Comment: Why you accepted the other answer?? I had answered already!

Comment: @kevinsantos
Thats right that the enemy's button has got .character-box class dynamically but it worked because it was already there on DOM. And that is why your 1st click event `$(".character-box").on("click", function(){});`  worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could **delegate**

```
$(document).on("click", ".enemyplayer", function(){
    alert("lets fight");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add even listener after you create button, like this:

```
var myEnemy = $("<button>");
var enemyimage = $("<img>");
var enemyName = enemies["enemy"+j].name;
var enemyImgSrc = enemies["enemy"+j].imgsrc;
myEnemy.attr("id",(enemyName+"BAD"));
myEnemy.addClass("character-box enemyplayer");
enemyimage.attr("src", enemyImgSrc);
enemyimage.addClass("gameSprite")
$("#enemybox").append(myEnemy);
$("#"+enemyName+"BAD").append(enemyimage);

// add here
$(".enemyplayer").on("click", function(){
  alert("lets fight");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to resolve the issue with click event, simply extend jQuery with your own functions.

```
myEnemy.attr('onClick', '$.fn.ClickMe()');

$.fn.ClickMe = function () {
    alert('You clicked me !!!'); 
}
```

I think, its easiest way to deal with, instead of class delegation, because in future if some one decide to change class then it will impacted whole stuff.